# How to insert data for two tables with one to many relationship in Laravel using one controller function

Tags: php, laravel

using Laravel two tables students and titles. Student Model one to many relationship with Title Model.
Student Model

```
protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'stu_no';

    public function titles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'stu_no','stu_no');
    }
```

Title Model

```
protected $fillable = ['title','from_date','to_date'];


    public function student(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'stu_no');
    }
```

and my StudentController

```
 public function addStudent(Request $request) {
        $student = Student::create($request->all());
        return response($student, 201);
   }
```

and api route is

```
Route::post('addStudent','App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@addStudent');
```

this is working fine. but now I need add titles data also using same StudentController function `addStudent` then how can I manage this?

Comment: `$student = Employee::create(...)` - Huh? What is `Employee`? Is that supposed to be `Student`? But you can do `$student->titles()->create(...)` in the same Controller.

Comment: @TimLewis sorry for mistaken. I fixed the error. you mean `$student = $student->titles()->create($request->all());`

Comment: All good! And no, I mean `$student = Student::create($request->all());`, _then_ `$title = $student->titles()->create(...)` (replacing `...` with the appropriate data).